# Referencing Model with String input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I wish to make a page that can query the desired object with type(string) and id(int).

> /query?type=people&id=1

would fetch me

> Person.find(1)

whereas

> /query?type=cities&id=123

would fetch me

> City.find(123)

However, I have problems as to how to translate strings into the desired model class.

The only way I can think of is

```
case params[:type]
 when 'people'
  @object = Person.find(params[:id])
 when 'cities'
  @object = City.find(params[:id])
end
```

However, this method will be quite problematic if I have more types of models.

Is there a better way?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: If you try to do this automatically you may end up in a situation where an attacker can send "/query?type=TOP_SECRET_TABLE&id=1" and get information he shouldn't be allowed to access. Beware of what you wish for.

Comment: It is actually meant for the ajax for tagging objects. So my next step would be like @object.tags << tag. But wanted to keep the question simple so asked this way. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try:

```
klass = params[:type]
klass.singularize.classify.constantize.find(params[:id])
```

Edit:

```
@object = params[:type].singularize.classify.constantize.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Your code doesnt work out of the box, but I edited and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: By 2021 `.constantize` alone would do the trick source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize