# Referencing method or property with String input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a rails function which can add either a Car or a Building object to a City object.

The first part of the function is to create the Car or Building object with the given name, then append it to the city's list of cars or buildings.

```
def addObject(obj_type,obj_name,city_id)
  new_obj = obj_type.constantize.create(:name => obj_name)
  city = City.find(city_id)

  city.obj_type.underscore.pluralize << new_obj
end
```

With `Inflector`, the program can use `constantize` to reference the desired model class.

(thanks to [Referencing Model with String input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462785/referencing-model-with-string-input))

Eg:

```
new_obj = obj_type.constantize.create(:name => obj_name)
```

However, when trying to access the lists inside the `City` object,

```
obj_type.underscore.pluralize
```

can turn "Car" into "cars"

however, it will only works as a bare string as the follow will not work:

```
city.obj_type.underscore.pluralize #city.cars desired
```

will some sort of metaprogramming functions such as `eval()` be required?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Have you seen `Inflector#tableize`?

Comment: Seems to do the same thing as `Inflector#underscore` and `Inflector#pluralize` together. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
city.send(obj_type.underscore.pluralize) << new_obj
```

In this case you create the method you want call on your city objet and use it by the send